# LTSpice subckt error

Tags: ltspice, simulation, model

I want to create a LISN module in LTSpice. For this I tried to make a subcircuit by first adding the RLC components and saving it as lisn.asy. Then I copied the netlist onto notepad and added :-

.subckt LISN1 line eut lisn gnd

I saved this in the same directory as the lisn.asy and tried to run the simulation of the circuit (shown in figure). I get the error

[image: error]

I thought this was because I had not added the ".lib" line in my subckt definition. I want to add it under [Misc] as a separate component. How do I do this?

This is my netlist:-

[image: netlist]

[image: ltspice]

EDIT 1:
I followed [this link](https://forum.digikey.com/t/making-sub-circuits-hierarchical-circuits-in-ltspice/2038) and [this approach](http://www.bot-thoughts.com/2009/10/custom-components-in-ltspice.html) too, but still got errors. I worked around this problem by simply adding the whole LISN circuit itself in my schematic instead of adding a subcircuit (but I want to know what's wrong anyways).

Comment: Nothing makes sense. You saved the RLC as `.asy`, then loaded the `.subckt`, but then you want to add `.lib` under `[Misc]`??? Best use the [LTspice groups](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/) for this. It would help to gather your thoughts and describe exactly what you did and how, step by step. What you've written here is too confusing.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen what I want to do is make LISN module.I see in examples online some have first made the circuit using existing components(in my case RLC)added the input outputs, saved this.Then copied its netlist and added the .subckt lines in notepad,saving this as a .lib file,preferably with the same name. I did not add any .lib line at first and then got the error.I thought this was where the problem was.

Comment: You need to understand a lot of nuances of LTspice to make proper subcircuits and symbols for them which automatically reference those subcircuits.  I suggest learning how to use "hierarchical blocks" instead:  https://www.audio-perfection.com/spice-ltspice/hierarchical-blocks-in-ltspice.html

Comment: @SteKulov Thank you for the link.So I should have made a hierarchical block instead of a .subckt? What I want to understand is if I want to use a component that is absent in LTSpice (like this LISN module) what do I add it under? Or have I not got to add it this way? This is in reference to the first link in my post.

Comment: @SM32 I guess what I'm saying is that since you're working solely within LTspice, it's unnecessary to "compile" your schematic down into a generic netlist to create a subcircuit which can be used in all SPICE programs.  LTspice has the ability to bypass that step and work with schematics directly, which is what "hierarchical blocks" are.  If you don't want to do that and still want to mess with subcircuit netlists, then use this procedure to make it easier for you to generate the symbol:  https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks for the info, I'll check out this method after hierarchical blocks.